# Get nested data from Firebase v9 in React v18

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My data path in firebase looks like this: Users >
rSzP3dXordco4i4EMLORZSYWuyN2 > anime > eFfOzOkqUmIl8acj6lAo Users and
anime are collections and id's are documents

The code with which I try to get data are:

```
const [anime, setAnime]=useState([]);
const [uid, setUid]=useState('')

const fetchAnime = async () => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUid(user.uid)
    } 
  });
  let getAnime = await getDocs(collection(db,"Users", uid,"anime"))
  setAnime(getAnime.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})))
}

useEffect(()=>{
fetchAnime()
},[])
```

I get error code that collection reference must have odd number of
segments but I tried multiple ways and for some reason they do not
count in the uid. Uid was checked with console log and it fetches it
correctly. Once user is created, user document id is copied and is
assigned to firestore to have data by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged()` loads user information asynchronously so your query is mostly running even before the auth state has loaded and hence value of `uid` is `""`. Also there's no need to store the UID in state for this unless there's any other use case. Instead your should run the query within `onAuthStateChanged()` as shown below:

```
const [anime, setAnime] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      let getAnime = await getDocs(collection(db, "Users", user.uid, "anime"))
      setAnime(getAnime.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id
      })))
    }
  });
}, [])
```

Comment: Now I keep getting error : Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: @Deividas the function should be async to use await. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you for saving and explaining for the second time now. I appreciate it

Comment: yes, will do it, new to using the stack overflow as well, till recently I only used it for reading answers